# Need to make a wish list / favourites system

Tags: plugins

Has anyone made a plugin which allows for a visitor/user to remember an entry and then see a list of them?

I need to make a "short list" page for our new site.

I was sure there was a plugin that did this, but I can't for the life of me find it anywhere now!

Comment: Ahha! Think I've found it https://github.com/lorigoldberg/curate/

Comment: Did you manage to make Curate work - it's just what we need but won't work :-(

Comment: I did, I've submitted a pull request but not heard back. Here's the link to my repo which should work fine in Craft 2.2 https://github.com/neondigital/curate/tree/fixes

Comment: Thanks That is great! I have installed your version and "Add Favourite" is working and I can see the entries in the DB. The getFaves sample is not working. Using 
  {% set faves = craft.curate.getFavesByUserId(currentUser.id) %}

     
  
  {% for fave in faves %}
   <li><a href="{{ fave.url }}">{{ fave.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %} 

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Glen, sorry to ask again but I wandered if your getFavesByUserId was working, and how, as it's not working here despite there being data in the table?

Comment: This works for us... {% if user %}{% set faves = craft.curate.getFavesByUserId(currentUser.id) %} {% for fave in faves %}...

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit late for your specific question, but [Shortlist for Craft](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist) is designed for exactly this.

(I'm the developer).

It's [also available for EE](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine)

Answer (score 1):

https://dukt.net/craft/like

I think Dukt is working on something like this.

Comment: I saw that, but wasn't any information or download ;(

Comment: For those who might stumble upon this. The download button is there under the main h1 and lead in paragraph and the docs are present as well.